# Why does the actions/functions within call back from load() get actioned 4 times and how do I fix?

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with my jQuery code.
When I click the button everything within the callback from my ajax.load() request seems to get actioned 4 times and I do not undestand why.

```
$('#requestDetails').click(function(event) {
    if($('form#forgotForm').length == 0){
        $('.innerBox').fadeTo('fast',0,function() {
            $('.innerBox').load('includes/ajax/forms.php?form=forgot',function(){
                enable_Forgot();
                clearWarnings();

                var $height = $('#loginContainer').outerHeight();
                $('#containerBox').animate({height:$height},'fast', function(){
                    $('.innerBox').fadeTo('fast',1);
                    //console.log('fade in Inner Block - Done');

                }); 

            });

        });
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**UPDATE:** thanks for your help guys - good spot.

my solution was to specify the parent element in the selector so that it would be specify only one of the elements with the same class.

```
            $('#loginContainer > .innerBox').fadeTo('fast',0,function() {
            $(this).load('includes/ajax/forms.php?form=forgot',function(){
                enable_Forgot();
                clearWarnings();
                //rest of code would follow...
```

This has fixed my issue as far as I can tell but I dont have my javaconsole at work to check my debug log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be here...

```
$('.innerBox').fadeTo('fast',0,function() {
```

Do you by any chance have 4 elements with class="innerBox" - if so, this line will cause everything wrapped within the function to occur once for each of these 4 boxes.

If that isn't the problem, can you show us your HTML?

Update based on comments...

Yes - you have 2 class="innerBox" elements, so your code flow is as follows...

```
$('.innerBox').fadeTo('fast',0,function() {
// "for each element with a class of innerBox (2) execute the following line"

    $('.innerBox').load('includes/ajax/forms.php?form=forgot',function(){
    // "for each element with a class of innerBox (2) perform a get and load the result"
```

So you have 2x2 ajax requests!

You might want to try...

```
$.get("includes/ajax/forms.php?form=forgot", function (data) {
    $(".innerBox").html(data);
});
```

Although I'm not sure why you would want to load the same thing into both inner boxes, so you might want to specifically select just one of them.

Comment: the mark up is viewable here op.liquidfists.com/index2.php just click view source, no there is only 1 element with the class name .innerBox

Comment: I have notice that i have specified $('.innerBox') and $('.innerBox') but they are one and the same maybe I should use $(this) after the first $('.innerBox') call?

Comment: I see two `$('.innerBox')` on the page you mentioned.

Comment: yes I call $('.innerBox') three times once to fadeTo 0 once to load a form asycronsyly and once again to fadeTo 1 when the form has loaded. but there is only one element in my markup that has the class .innerBox

Comment: my mistake there is 2 elements with the same class good spot.